# Basic manipulation of a UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, image-manipulation

I'm learning about basic manipulation of `UIImage`s using Objective-C on iOS. Say I have a square 128x128 image. **How can I crop the bottom half of the image and store just the top half in a 128x64 image?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is get a smaller CGImageRef from the UIImage's CGImage:

```
CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], someRect);
```

With that image you can then create a new image:

```
UIImage *nImage = [UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:nImageRef];
```

Oops almost forgot, after you do the above:

```
CGImageRelease(nImageRef);
```